# Is there standard C++ template class for variable-length arrays with maximum size for good cache locality?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, boost, stl

I'm developing a software where cache locality is king. It uses about 10 different C arrays in complex data structures that have `#define MAX_ARRAY_1_SIZE 1000` like defines. The number of elements in this example 1 array can be then between 0-1000. There are arrays of structs within arrays of structs. The amount of memory used is about 163 megabytes.

However, I noticed C's `qsort` is slow so I switched to `C++` which has much faster `std::sort` due to inlining the comparator function call. The wonders of template metaprogramming.

Now I'm wondering whether I should use C++'s more advanced features. I tried `std::vector` in just two of the about 10 arrays, only to find out it kills my cache locality, leading to 15% performance reduction when only two arrays of the about 10 were replaced by `std::vector`. Yes, I did find out it was due to cache locality: during the critical code path, the array size remains unchanged and it's only populated at program startup time.

Then I tried to see whether there is something that stores the elements in-line, not in a separate dynamically allocated block. I found `std::array`. However, `std::array` is a fixed size array and the benefit over C arrays is questionable.

I'm looking for a variable-sized array with maximum size and inline element storage. Is there such a thing in standard C++? Or in Boost?

It doesn't hurt if the variable-sized array actually could have infinite maximum size, so that it stores data in an in-line array if the data fits there, and resorts to using an allocated array if the data doesn't fit in the in-line array.

Now, an experienced C++ programmer could write such a template class in few hours, and I could do the same in few days due to using C++ last time about 10 years ago before I had to obtain the `std::sort` performance increase now. But I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I'm looking for existing solutions.

**Edit:**

To make myself clear, let me provide an example:

```
struct baz {
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct bar {
  struct baz baz[100];
};

struct foo {
  struct bar bar[100];
};
```

Now `struct foo` is one contiguous block of memory.

```
struct baz {
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct bar {
  std::vector<struct baz> baz;
};

struct foo {
  std::vector<struct bar> bar;
};
```

...now it isn't.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "nline element storage"?

Comment: A variable-sized array with contiguous array storage.... so a `std::vector`? Doesn't get more cache-friendly than that unless you start playing games with padding and alignment.

Comment: No! `std::vector` allocates a separate block. If you have array of `struct foo`, and a vector within it, the values in the vector are not contiguously in the memory if observed across the numerous vectors. Each vector has a separate block.

Comment: wouldn't custom allocator with placement new work here? allocate pool, create storages later

Comment: wouldn't custom allocator with placement new work here? allocate pool, create storages later

Comment: If you sort multiple `foo`, `vector<bar>` would be superior as the move would be cheap whereas it would be equivalent to a copy with `bar[100];`.

Comment: You do not need to use vector to use std::sort. You just need to make your class ranges: you can provide a begin and end method, that return pointer to the first end one past the last initialized element, and that is it, you already have written the most complex part of container implementation in your C code I imagine.

Comment: It doesn't sound like using C++ for the containers is going to get you any improvements. I'd probably stick with the code you have now and just make sure I could use `std::sort` instead of `qsort`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many small vector classes out there.  Boost has some.  Try http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.small_vector

An easy hand rolled solition with only a bit of overhead would be a gsl span attached to a variant of vector and std array.  There is overhead over the most optimal solution of a few bytes.  Interact using the span over the unknown container.

Comment: We had the same idea. Basically, this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZOd2ZkV8Q1szjJE0

Comment: Oh. It seems I kinda missed the requirement/wish for dynamically _resizing_ too. Oh well, it's the same idea, still but I don't think the gain of reusing `span<T>` is quite so appealing anymore because you'll still find yourself duplicating vector-like interface.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to implement my own:

```
template<class C, class sz_t, sz_t maxsz> class inlinearray {
  private:
    typedef C value_type;
    typedef value_type *pointer;
    typedef const value_type *const_pointer;
    typedef value_type &reference;
    typedef const value_type &const_reference;
    typedef value_type *iterator;
    typedef const value_type *const_iterator;
    typedef sz_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;
    sz_t sz;
    union {
      C realarray[maxsz]; // for correct alignment
      char array[maxsz*sizeof(C)];
    };
  public:
    inlinearray()
    {
      sz = 0;
    }
    ~inlinearray(void)
    {
      clear();
    }
    void clear(void)
    {
      sz_t i;
      for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
      {
        data()[i].~C();
      }
      sz = 0;
    }
    template<class sz2_t, sz2_t maxsz2> inlinearray(inlinearray<C,sz2_t,maxsz2> that)
    {
      size_t i;
      sz = that.sz;
      for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
      {
        push_back(that[i]);
      }
    }
    template<class sz2_t, sz2_t maxsz2> void operator=(inlinearray<C,sz2_t, maxsz2> val2)
    {
      swap(val2);
    }
    void fill(const C& val)
    {
      std::fill_n(begin(), size(), val);
    }
    C &operator[](sz_t i) noexcept
    {
      return data()[i];
    }
    constexpr const C &operator[](sz_t i) const noexcept
    {
      return data()[i];
    }
    C at(sz_t i)
    {
      if (i >= sz)
      {
        throw std::out_of_range("inlinerray::at() out of range");
      }
      return data()[i];
    }
    constexpr const C at(sz_t i) const
    {
      if (i >= sz)
      {
        throw std::out_of_range("inlinerray::at() out of range");
      }
      return data()[i];
    }
    void push_back(const C &c)
    {
      if (sz >= maxsz)
      {
        abort();
      }
      new (data()+sz) C(c);
      sz++;
    }
    void pop_back() noexcept
    {
      data()[sz-1].~C();
      sz--;
    }
    template <class sz2_t, sz2_t maxsz2> void swap(inlinearray<C, sz2_t, maxsz2> &that)
    {
      if (that.sz > maxsz)
      {
        abort();
      }
      if (sz > that.maxsz)
      {
        abort();
      }
      std::swap_ranges(begin(), end(), that.begin());
      std::swap(sz, that.sz);
    }
    constexpr sz_t size(void) const noexcept { return sz; }
    constexpr sz_t max_size(void) const noexcept { return maxsz; }
    constexpr bool empty() const noexcept { return sz == 0; }
    C *begin() noexcept { return data(); }
    C &front() noexcept { return data()[0]; }
    C &back() noexcept { return sz == 0 ? data()[0] : data()[sz - 1]; }
    constexpr const C &back() const noexcept { return sz == 0 ? data()[0] : data()[sz - 1]; }
    C *end() noexcept { return data() + sz; }
    C* data() noexcept { return reinterpret_cast<C*>(array); }
    const C* data() const noexcept { return reinterpret_cast<const C*>(array); }
    const C *begin() const noexcept { return data(); }
    const C *end() const noexcept { return data() + sz; }
    const C *cbegin() const noexcept { return data(); }
    const C *cend() const noexcept { return data() + sz; }
    reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept { return reverse_iterator(end()); }
    reverse_iterator rend() noexcept { return reverse_iterator(begin()); }
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept { return const_reverse_iterator(end()); }
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept { return const_reverse_iterator(begin()); }
    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept { return const_reverse_iterator(end()); }
    const_reverse_iterator crend() const noexcept { return const_reverse_iterator(begin()); }
};
```

Usage of the code should be straightforward.

Comment: This doesn't support switching between small inplace data and larger remote data?

Comment: No, not yet. I could add it as an improvement later.